# Alsa Headers not found in Ubuntu 9.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu-9.04, kubuntu, alsa

I want to run my programs which I was running in Fedora core 6 which uses alsa apis, In FC6 I had alsa headers in /usr/include/alsa folder. In Ubuntu 9.04, I search whole file system but cant find alsa headers like asoundlib, asoundef.h, input.h, output.h, etc.

Please tell me how can I get it?

Answer,

do

```
sudo aptitude install libasound2-dev
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say do a

`sudo aptitude install libasound2-dev`

Comment: Thanks, It worked but it installed headers in /usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.28-11/include/sound not in /usr/include/alsa/. do you know the reason?

Comment: probalby because this is kernel related anyway.

Comment: Hi Ragez, Still I cant find asoundlib.h.

Comment: if you install `libclalsadrv-dev`

Comment: global.h, input.h, and some other. Can you please tell me how to get all these.

Comment: I installed libclalsadrv-dev but still cant find asoundlib.h

Comment: try `libasound2-dev` I think that's the good one!

Comment: `/usr/include/alsa/asoundlib.h` here we go sorry I am not an ubuntu package expert and the package website of ubuntu is down now!

Comment: with libasound2-dev installation it worked. Thanks.

Comment: RageZ, How can I find that which header is in which package ? Is there any website or tool for it?